# Alternative to @page size for browsers that don't support it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Mostly develop in Chrome and something like the following works as expected:

```
@media print {
  @page {
    size: letter portait;
    margin: 0in; 
  }
}
```

Although CanIUse.com says Firefox isn't compatible, it seems to be working fine for me for the time being:

https://caniuse.com/#search=%40page

However, Edge, IE, and Safari it doesn't not work like CanIUse says.

What is an alternative to achieve the same thing? Doing the following maybe:

```
@media print {
  body {
    width: 8.5in;
    height: 11in;
    margin: 0in; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposal would basically work. I'd actually recommend just writing your styles without using `@page` at all since there is still pretty limited support for it. Writing a single `@media print` query that works the same in all browsers is going to be easier than trying to have one version with `@page` and then a fallback.

If you want to preview the styles for your print media without having to constantly click the print button, just [use your browser's developer tools to test the media you are testing](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2012/12/12/debugging-print-stylesheets-now-significantly-easier-in-chrome/). It's going to take a little trial and error at first.

Also, for `0` value properties, you do not need to include the unit. `margin: 0` is sufficient.